# Ext JS 5.1 : Unable to title of panel when collapsible true

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Ext JS 5.1. I have simple panel with title and collapsible. But not able see title when collapsible is true

```
{
   xtype: 'panel',
   title: 'Type',           
   collapsible: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/iv6):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            width: 200,
            collapsible: true,
            html: '<p>World!</p>',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

It must be related to your config, please post a complete example of your code to replicate the issue and I will update the answer.

Comment: Understood. This is very obvious. I am using nested panel. Suspecting either layout or width issue.